# Ember.js with Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for and polymorphic has_many/belongs_to

Tags: json, api, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4

On the Rails API side I have the following 2 models:

```
class Grower < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

as well as a Growers controller which returns and can create/update Growers with embedded Addresses attributes. I also have an Addresses controller with proper routing so that Addresses can be viewed/created/updated for a specific Grower. The latter is more of an "in-case", and I'm not sure I'll be needing to return/update/create addresses as a separate payload.

I am starting to try and piece together an Ember app that would allow me to view/edit/create a Grower at the same time as its Address(es). Can anyone point me to an existing real or sample app that does this? I will be posting my code as I go along, but I already have an idea of some areas where I will be running into trouble:

1. Rails returns/expects nested params named **addresses_attributes**. Ember, I am sure, doesn't use that convention. What's the best approach of resolving this?
2. Because of the polymorphic association (objects other than Grower can be addressable), on the API/Address side, to get the correct belongs_to object, Rails uses **addressable_id** in conjunction with **addressable_type**. In this example the addressable_type would be "Grower", and the addressable_id would be the grower_id value. How would one go about translating that on the Ember side?

UPDATE:

I got it to work at least a couple different ways. My preferred solution, at least for this particular case, is in the answer section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a couple ways to get it done, but the final approach doesn't require any changes on the Rails/API side.

On the client (Ember) side:

1. I added the **addresses** hasMany property to the App.Grower model. I also mapped it on the RESTAdapter to what's expected from the API, by setting the **key** for *addresses* to **addresses_attributes**.
2. I added the **grower** (for now - will change to **addressable** once I have other *addressable* models) belongsTo property on App.Address. It's not really required for what I'm doing, but it might be useful in the future.
3. I set the *addresses* on the **RESTAdapter** to be **embedded: 'always'**.
4. On the **App.GrowersEditController**, I just do a *model.save* (*transaction.commit*), and the child addresses are automatically saved via the API call.
5. On the App.GrowersAddController, I use the **App.Address.createRecord** and **App.Grower.createRecord** methods using the user-entered Grower and Address data. Then I use the **pushObject** method to append the Address to the Grower, and then call a *save* on the Grower (*commit* on transaction). Again, the address data gets submitted and saved automatically.

Comment: @yuri Inseated of has_many I have a belongs_to relationship, so I would like to have something like address_attributes to send to the server. A tip would be very appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a sample of code based @yuяi's strategy that worked well for me:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend
    comments: DS.hasMany('comment')

App.PostSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend( DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,
    attrs:
        comments: {embedded: 'always'}

    keyForAttribute: (attr) ->
        if attr == "comments"
            "comments_attributes"
        else
            @_super(attr)
)
```

This solution worked well with Ember **1.6.1** and Ember Data **1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a**.

Comment: check this open issue for a fix some time in the future https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1950